# rgl plot3d and snapshot3d: how do I save with resolution higher than my monitor?

Tags: r

I am saving several plots, made with rgl's functions `plot3d` and `snapshot3d`. I need to save some at very high resolution, higher my screen.
When I use

```
par3d("windowRect" = c(x,y,w,h))
```

to set the window dimension just before calling `snapshot3d` it works but the resolution is limited to my monitor's width or height.
Is there a way to break this limit?
Thank you all for your time.

Comment: I don't think so.  Are you working on a system that would allow you to set up a virtual frame buffer (Xvfb) ?

Comment: Running OSX 10.9.5 which does not include Xvfb anymore. Unless there are ways to install it, the answer is no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution I found to save in high resolution is to move away from the `snapshot3d` function and use `rgl.postscript` to save to a vector format like svg. This allows me to rasterize later with the resolution I want.

Example:

```
rgl.postscript("graph.svg", fmt="svg")
```

The function `rgl.snapshot` really grabs a snapshot from the device and I think there's no way to break screen's boundaries using this function unless, as Ben Bolker points out in the comments (thanks), a virtual frame buffer is used.